# How to print unicode character from a string variable?

Tags: python, string, unicode, printf

I am new in programming world, and I am a bit confused.

I expecting that both print result the same graphical unicode exclamation mark symbol:

My experiment:

```
number   = 10071
byteStr  = number.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')
hexStr   = hex(number)
uniChar  = byteStr.decode('utf-32be')
uniStr   = '\\u' + hexStr[2:6]
print(f'{number} - {hexStr[2:6]} - {byteStr} - {uniChar}')

print(f'{uniStr}')   # Not working
print(f'\u2757')     # Working
```

Output:

```
10071 - 2757 - b"\x00\x00'W" - ❗
\u2757
❗
```

What are the difference in the last two lines?
Please, help me to understand it!

My environment is JupyterHub and v3.9 python.

Comment: `'\\u' + ...` literally creates a string with a backslash, u and some numbers. `\u....` in a string literal is an escape sequence for a Unicode characters. Strings are *not* evaluated again after the fact for escape sequences.

Comment: MAybe you are looking for `chr(0x2757)`: the function which transform codepoints into characters

Comment: @deceze and Giacomo Catenazzi thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An escape code evaluated by the Python parser when constructing literal strings.  For example, the literal string `'马'` and `'\u9a6c'` are evaluated by the parser as the same, length 1, string.

You can (and did) build a string with the 6 characters `\u9a6c` by using an escape code for the backslash (`\\`) to prevent the parser from evaluating those 6 characters as an escape code, which is why it prints as the 6-character `\u2757`.

If you build a byte string with those 6 characters, you can decode it with `.decode('unicode-escape')` to get the character:

```
>>> b'\\u2757'.decode('unicode_escape')
'❗'
```

But it is easier to use the `chr()` function on the number itself:

```
>>> chr(0x2757)
'❗'
>>> chr(10071)
'❗'
```

Comment: Dear @Mark Tolonenm Thanks for your help!!!
These two things helped me to understand what is going on:
1. "Python parser when constructing literal strings."
2. "same, length 1, string."